# Combination with repetition: Finding the number of negative, zero, and positive integer solutions of an equation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, integer-partitions

Equation:

$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 32$

Constraint:

$x_i => -2$ where 1 <= i <= 4

What is the strategy to solve this through combination with repetition?

Comment: $x_i\geq -2\implies x_i+2\geq 0$.  Make a change of variables... letting $y_i=x_i+2$.  What is $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4$ knowing that $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=32$?  Is solving for the number of non-negative solutions of $y_i$ easier for you to do?

Comment: @MathLover order almost surely matters... this is a very routine exercise in stars-and-bars.  Breaking into cases, while feasible, is highly inefficient and is not the recommended approach here.

Comment: @JMoravitz Now that **y** comes into play, it seems a familiar problem. I came up with this equation from $y_i = x_i$: 

$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 + 8 = 40$.

Now we solve $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = 40$ for non-negative integers. Right?

Comment: @YoonesMehdian precisely.